# MySQL Matching Columns from Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Ok a little primer; I'm an expert PHP/JS/C developer but have never quite been able to get a comprehensive grasp on MySQL.  It would be great if you could answer my question, but just as helpful if you could point me in the direction of *good* resources to learn about complex MySQL query do's and don'ts (mostly from an efficiency standpoint).

**Objective**

I need to find similarities/overlaps in a single table while still pulling the entire result set (to LEFT JOIN with the actual title/description content which is in another table).

The table is extremely simple; it contains 3 columns (`page`, `user`, `time`).

Essentially each query will have two users.  I need to pull the count of all results matching `User 1`, the count of all results matching `User 2`, and ALL columns (plus LEFT JOIN) for overlap (where both `User 1` and `User 2` have a match in the table.

**Sample Query**

This query works, but it's extremely slow (to the point where it takes minutes to run) and I'm guessing inefficient due to the subqueries.  If any SQL experts can point out a more efficient way to do this (and why) it would be MUCH appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `page`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `m_likes` WHERE `user` = "1") AS userLikes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `m_likes` WHERE `user` = "2") AS friendLikes

    FROM `m_likes` LEFT JOIN `app_pages` AS page ON (page.id = `page`)

        WHERE `page` IN (SELECT `page` FROM `m_likes` WHERE `user` = "1") 
        AND `page` IN (SELECT `page` FROM `m_likes` WHERE `user` = "2")

        AND (`user` = "1" OR `user` = "2")
```

**EXPLAIN Query Results**

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     m_likes index   NULL    page    604 NULL    35043   Using where; Using index; Using temporary
1   PRIMARY     page    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 767 tablename.m_likes.page  1   
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  m_likes unique_subquery page    page    604 func,const      1   Using index; Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  m_likes unique_subquery page    page    604 func,const      1   Using index; Using where
3   SUBQUERY    m_likes index   NULL    page    604 NULL    35043   Using where; Using index
2   SUBQUERY    m_likes index   NULL    page    604 NULL    35043   Using where; Using index
```

**Table Schema**

**app_pages**: `id` VARCHAR(255), `name` VARCHAR(255), `category` VARCHAR(255)

**m_likes**: `page` VARCHAR(255), `user` VARCHAR(255), `time` INT(20)

m_likes.page = app_pages.id

Also worth noting, unfortunately the User & Page IDs must be VARCHAR instead of INT, as there is no guarantee of this being run on a 64-bit system, and some of the ID values are larger than the max allowed on a 32-bit system... Hopefully that doesn't add a major performance hit.

**Output Example**

```
array (size=156)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'page' => string '100861973286778' (length=15)
      'time' => string '1297383617' (length=10)
      'name' => string 'Leila' (length=5)
      'category' => string 'Book' (length=4)
      'userLikes' => string '104' (length=3)
      'friendLikes' => string '52' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'page' => string '10150160788195604' (length=17)
      'time' => string '1272653871' (length=10)
      'name' => string 'Frisbee Golfing' (length=15)
      'category' => string 'Interest' (length=8)
      'userLikes' => string '104' (length=3)
      'friendLikes' => string '52' (length=2)
```

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to better understand how MySQL executes your query

Comment: I already tried using EXPLAIN but frankly it wasn't that useful; The query executed exactly as I expected, but it doesn't give me any insights into how to BETTER design it which is what I'm hoping an SQL expert will.

Comment: Can you post the results here?

Comment: @Julian, it would be easier for us to decipher your problem if you posted your table schema (columns in `m_likes` and `app_pages`)

Comment: EXPLAIN results posted in question; formatting issues in comments.  Table Schema added.

Comment: @Julian, can you come up with some simplified example data and the result you would expect from a query on that data?

Comment: @Julian, is this what your data looks along the lines of: [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/226dc/3/1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/226dc/3/1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your query is running so slow is because you're performing **FOUR** separate subqueries which actually end up executing for **EACH** row.

Instead, you can do a Cartesian product of a subselect to get *total* counts (only executes one time):

```
SELECT a.page, c.userLikes, c.friendLikes
FROM m_likes a
INNER JOIN app_pages b ON a.page = b.id
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN user = '1' THEN 1 END) AS userLikes,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN user = '2' THEN 1 END) AS friendLikes
    FROM m_likes
    WHERE user IN ('1','2')
) c
WHERE a.user IN ('1','2')
GROUP BY a.page
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```

This query will retrieve all pages that user 1 and 2 both liked, along with the total counts of their likes (which will be repeated in the result-set).

Comment: Tried this query, but it doesn't seem to work with the HAVING COUNT(1) = 2... I took that part out to test the rest and it appears fine, but it's selecting the entire results set (I'm guessing the HAVING statement is the part that actually breaks down the subset).  Any idea what might be off there?  [edit] After looking into the HAVING command it seems I just need to figure out the alias for the temporary column created by the CASE (which doesn't seem to be '1')

Comment: @Julian, could you explain what's actually wrong with the result-set when you put in the `HAVING` clause? Does it generate an error? The `HAVING` clause here basically selects all pages that both user `1` and `2` liked. This is assuming the combination of the fields `page -> user` is unique (user can't like a page more than once).

Comment: @Julian Also, at this point, it would be VERY helpful if you posted some example data from both of your tables, and desired output.

Comment: When I add the `HAVING` clause it returns nothing--an empty response, but no SQL error.  The actual user IDs are of course different than 1/2, but I tried every permutation of the COUNT(a) = b assuming user ID a/b.

Comment: added the output example to original question

Comment: @Julian, the `2` in the `HAVING` clause is not a user id, but rather it is the count of items in the list you're filtering on: Ex. `WHERE a.user IN ('1','2')` has two items in the list. We want to select pages where **two** rows were returned (meaning both user ids liked the page).

Comment: @Julian, the `1` in `COUNT(1)` does not mean anything, it just counts the mere existence of a row. `COUNT(*)` could also be used, but just as a matter of style, I tend to use `1` inside `COUNT()`.

Comment: Got it, after all that it turns out the hardcoded user ID was off by one digit--the query worked perfectly; thanks!